# Firebase Auth does not work with Twitter API v2?

Tags: firebase, twitter, firebase-authentication

Looks like Firebase JS lib doesn't work with Twitter API v2?

I see the following error message.

```
index.js:1 FirebaseError: Firebase: Failed to fetch resource from 
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json?include_email=true, 
http status: 403, 
http response: {"errors":[
   {"message":"You currently have Essential access which includes access 
               to Twitter API v2 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, 
                you’ll need to apply for Elevated access via the Developer Portal. 
                You can learn more here: 
                https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-leve","code":453}]}
```

Comment: Interesting. The verify credentials endpoint is not strictly required for login but it is possible that Firebase is using it. You can apply for elevated access (free) to get v1.1 endpoint access and use Firebase though.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to know the steps for Twitter elevated access, please follow the attached image steps:
[image]
... for elevated access of Twitter.

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70383673/2227743).

Comment: @EricAya arguably, it's a more detailed image than the other answer & easier for beginners to follow.

Comment: then should've just edited the other answer

Comment: I thought this will take a few days. But i got access instantly when not asking for special usage (such as selecting tweet reading). Thanks, that was a great answer with better visual support!

Comment: This options no longer seems to be available.  Is there a new way to get past this error?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to apply for elevated access on the developer portal.
[image]